# Dynamics CRM storage for email attachment?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am working on a CRM project. I've been informed that the document storage within the CRM system is undergoing changes.
The documents will be relocated to Azure blob storage. We're developing a solution to enable emailing to a shared mailbox, with emails stored as attachments to the contact record and a case is created in CRM. Adhering to best practices, rather than storing documents in CRM, we recommend storing emails in SharePoint and creating links in CRM to reference the documents. Is it correct?

Comment: This is an opiniated topic. Some will definitely say no to email storage in SharePoint, others will think otherwise. SharePoint has a ton of optimizations regarding efficient blob storage and Dataverse now also has sound options in this field. In general I would never make solutions more complex than needed and choose for storage in CRM. Remember, creating a good integration with SharePoint can be more difficult than expected. But again, this is just an opinion.